# MCP23017 Failing After Several Minutes?

Tags: arduino, i2c

I just bought an MCP23017 port expander and hooked it up to my an Arduino card. I used the [sample code](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-MCP23017-Arduino-Library) to turn on four LEDs when the program launches. Works great, except that after several minutes all the LEDs switch off and won't come back on until I actually power down the entire card and plug it back in (hitting reset won't cut it). I've checked and rechecked and everything else looks fine. Is it possible I've got a bad I2C chip?

Comment: Does the toggle.pde example keep working? (longer than your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the hardware configured? Do you know how much current the LEDs are drawing? The [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21952b.pdf) says each pin can source or sink 25mA. That is reasonable for a typical, indicator LED, but you could be pushing it. Plus, the max current into Vdd is 125mA. It could be possible that the chip is shutting down the outputs until a hard reset to prevent overheating. If you are using transistors for the LEDs, it wouldn't matter. However, I'd be interested to see if you only used a couple LEDs and increased the series resistance for each such that they drew less current if that would fix the issue or not.

**Edit**

Pull the RESET pin up to 5V with a 10kΩ resistor. If not, it will just be floating. Once it drops below a certain threshold, it will reset the port expander.

Comment: I've got a 220 ohm resistor for each LED, A0-A3 on the chip connected to ground, 5V power and ground for VDD and VSS, plus the LEDs of course, which are connected to GPA4-GPA7. I'll try a going down to single LED.

Comment: Also, do you have the reset pin pulled up to Vdd? If not, it will just be floating. Once it drops below a certain threshold, it will reset the port expander.

http://davidn.org/wp/?p=89